# Cannot click an object in Katalon Studio

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, katalon-studio

I have some problems with Katalon Studio. I'm trying to do a simple thing, but when I'm trying to click on the search button, it doesn't work.

Also, it has a very long delay when the program opens a browser it takes 10-15 seconds to type a text in the search bar. Here is how the error looks like:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, share your script (go to the script tab shown on the screenshot) and all of the error logs (copy and paste text from the console view).

Comment: Now search button is working, but the wait time is too long. Here is my script --> WebUI.openBrowser('google.com')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Google/input_q'), 'something')

WebUI.closeBrowser()

Comment: Can you please show the error log?

Comment: end action: openBrowser was at 05:25:58 PM, start action: setText was at 05:25:58 PM and then it ended at 05:26:29 PM

Comment: it shows no error anymore, I just want to know why is the wait time too long ? Does it have an Explaining ?

Comment: It would be easier to troubleshoot with the logs (even without the error).

Comment: I updated my question with the new log.

Comment: First, it is better to copy/paste logs than to post screenshots. Second, please copy the logs from the  _console_ tab. And try adding `WebUI.waitForElementClickable(findTestObject('Page_Google/input_q'), 40)` before the `setText()` and report back.

Comment: Your 2 screenshots seem not for the same test case. There are some "Element not found" in the 2nd screenshot. When this error happens, timeout should be passed. That may be the reason why too slow.

Comment: Mate Mrse, Thank you it works now fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `WebUI.waitForElementClickable(findTestObject('Page_Google/input_q'), 40)` before the `WebUI.setText()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the log file, it seems that you executed the test with IE. Generally, Selenium is a bit slow working with IE. Hence, the slow in starting browser is predicted.

Regarding to clicking the search button (the image, i guessed), there are log mentioned that the element could not be found. You might need to double check on:
 - The image is clickable using WebUI.waitForElementClickable
 - The locator is correct at Object Repository.